# How to do external POST API call from F# code

Tags: web, f#, f#-data, f#-fake

I want to call external POST API from F# which has multipart form request body as below so how to do in F#?

```
External POST API
url : “https://”
Content-Type : Multipart/Form-data
Body :- key(file) -> value(file which is browsed)
key(secured) -> value(String)
```

Thanks for reading this question.

I tried the below code but didn't work for me

```
Http.Request
  ( "http://endpoint/for/multipart/data", 
  body = Multipart(
    boundary = "define a custom boundary here", // this is used to separate the items you're streaming
    parts = [
      MultipartItem("formFieldName", "file",IFormFile.OpenReadStream())
    ]


))
```

Comment: https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html 

is the source in case anyone is curious

Comment: When asking for help with a problem, it is generally helpful to describe the problem. Otherwise people trying to answer have to shoot in the dark trying to guess what your problem is.

Comment: "... didn't work for me" isn't enough information. What was the error message?

Comment: I want to do POST call for saving Image to blob but don't want to wait for result so how to do that POST call from F# code. I tried from here fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html but didn't work for me. Most of the method are wait to finish the post call execution and it's result also but I don't care  about response from post call

Answer (score 3):

I will use and HTTp client for this, in fsharp you can use various things like [F# Data: HTTP Utilities](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html) or and HTTP client package for that purpouse I recommend [HTTP.fs](https://github.com/haf/Http.fs):

Just create a console application and add this nuget packages

```
 dotnet new console -lang f# -o http-rest-client
 cd http-rest-client
 dotnet add package Http.fs
 dotnet add package Hopac
```

Then substitute the code in Program.fs with this:

// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

```
open System.IO
open System.Text
open Hopac
open HttpFs.Client

let multipartRequest =
    Request.createUrl Post "http://httpbin.org/post"
    |> Request.setHeader (Accept "application/json")
    |> Request.body (BodyForm [
        FormFile ("file", ("testfile.txt",
                           ContentType.create("text", "plain"),
                           Binary (File.ReadAllBytes ("./testfile.txt"))
                           ))])
    |> Request.responseAsString
    |> run
    


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%s" multipartRequest
    0
```

Create a file with, in this case to see it better a .txt file with a readable content. and [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) pfor testing purpouses, in my case the file contains:

```
➜ cat testfile.txt
calimero calimero calimero calimero
```

Then you can run your, project:

```
dotnet run

{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {
    "file": "calimero calimero calimero calimero\n"
  },
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Length": "241",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"BPj'o/kJ+CaKDQUuOnIaoLq/diChFH\"",
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "83.53.248.254, 83.53.248.254",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

The Http.fs package has a lot of examples for sending a form, and the library manages to add the headers that you need for `multipart-form-data`